# How to randomize text items in ListBox?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Good day! I would like to have help with my simple code from our programming project.
My problem is that I can't find a solution on how to randomize text items in the **listbox**. The items are read from my **MS Access** database. Here is some of my code.

```
Com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM search";
OleDbDataReader reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
object[] obj = new object[256];

while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(obj);

    if (label1.Text == obj[0].ToString())
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(1));
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(2));
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(3));
        listBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(4));
    }
}

reader.Close();
conn.Close();

Random random = new Random();
string[] words = { listBox1.Items.ToString() };
listBox4.Items.Add(words[random.Next(0, words.Length)]);
```

And it won't work.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"?  What error do you get?  What do you mean by "random text"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the items in the listbox in random order you can read the values into a list of strings, randomize them, and then add them to the listbox. Using the Shuffle-method in the answer to: [Randomize a List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp) it would look something like:

```
Com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM search";
OleDbDataReader reader = Com.ExecuteReader();
var words = new List<string>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (string.Compare(label1.Text, reader.GetString(0)) == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        {
            words.Add(reader.GetString(i));
        }
    }
}
reader.Close();
conn.Close();

listbox1.Items.AddRange(words.ToArray());
words.Shuffle();
listbox4.Items.AddRange(words.ToArray());
```

Add the following class to your system (using your namespace):

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Shuffle<T>(this IList<T> list)  
    {  
        Random rng = new Random();  
        int n = list.Count;  
        while (n > 1) {  
            n--;  
            int k = rng.Next(n + 1);  
            T value = list[k];  
            list[k] = list[n];  
            list[n] = value;  
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: sir thanks for the comment but sir i have an error here:

listBox1.Items.AddRange(words.ToArray());
            words.Shuffle();
            listBox4.Items.AddRange(words.ToArray());

it says that it does not contain a definition for "shuffle"
I've try and try to solve this but i Can't.

Comment: You have to include the function Shuffle from the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp. It's an extension method so if you copy paste it make sure you put it in a static class that is accessible from your code.

Comment: In my system sir is requires another class so that the items in my listbox will shuffled randomly. Sir can you give me a codes sir on how to add class sir? named Shuffle?

sorry for the disturbance sir :)

Comment: I Added the extension class and method to the answer.

Comment: sorry sir hehehe i didn't notice it, cause I'm focusing in my main codes. thanks again sir you helped me a lot..

Comment: No problem. If you feel this is the answer to your question, please mark it 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. :)